# How to add multiple text messages in following JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to display 5 to 10 text messages one after other, each message should appear in same div with rainbow color effect, code is given below. Only one message should appear at one time.

```
<!-- Add the below code 
where you wish the text to appear on the page: -->

<b>
<font size="5">
<script>

// ********** MAKE YOUR CHANGES HERE

var text="RAINBOW TEXT"     //   YOUR TEXT
var speed=80    //   SPEED OF FADE -     

// ********** LEAVE THE NEXT BIT ALONE!

// **** Do Not Alter Code Below ****
if (document.all||document.getElementById){
    document.write('<span id="highlight">' + text + '</span>')
    var storetext=document.getElementById?document.getElementById("highlight"):document.all.highlight
}
else
    document.write(text)

var hex=new     Array("00","14","28","3C","50","64","78","8C","A0","B4","C8","DC","F0")
var r=1
var g=1
var b=1
var seq=1

function changetext(){
    rainbow="#"+hex[r]+hex[g]+hex[b]
    storetext.style.color=rainbow
}

function change(){
    if (seq==6){
        b--

        if (b==0)
            seq=1
    }

    if (seq==5){
        r++

        if (r==12)
            seq=6
    }

    if (seq==4){
        g--

        if (g==0)
            seq=5
    }

    if (seq==3){
        b++

        if (b==12)
            seq=4
    }

    if (seq==2){
        r--

        if (r==0)
            seq=3
    }

    if (seq==1){
        g++

        if (g==12)
            seq=2
    }

    changetext()
}

function starteffect(){
    if (document.all||document.getElementById)
        flash=setInterval("change()",speed)
}

starteffect()
</script>
</font>
</b>
```

Comment: So you copied some code from somewhere but don't understand it and ask us to fix it? This is not how StackOverflow works. You need to be able to program. Then ask specific questions here. Don't ask us to do your work.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try something along these lines : If you want your words to appear one a at a time, at a given frequency, you could start by using

```
setInterval(callback, timer)
```

Which would allow you to call the "appearance function" every X seconds.

The callback function would be the function that add a word to your container. You could go for something like :

```
myContainer.innerHTML += '<span class="word">' + randomWord +'</span>';
```

If your words come from a prepared list of words, you can walk this list, one step per time the interval is run :

```
 var list = ["hello", "my", "name", "is", "Robert"];
 var current = 0;
 setInterval(function() {
     myContainer.innerHTML += '<span class="word">' + list[current] +'</span>';
     current++;
 }, 1000);
```

Don't forget to add your feature concerning the color change. You can calculate a new RGB code and add it as a style to each `<span>` tag that we add to the container. Another solution, if you do not intend to force a set of colors as you did, could be to consider this [blog article](https://rainbowcoding.com/how-to-create-rainbow-text-in-html-css-javascript/) which explains quite nicely how to implement a rainbow effect with pure CSS + it automatically extends the colors area as you add more words to your container. Unfortunately, you won't be able to always have a single color per word.

Then, be sure to stop the interval as soon as you've reached the end of your array :

```
 var list = ["hello", "my", "name", "is", "Robert"];
 var current = 0;
 var itv = setInterval(function() {
     myContainer.innerHTML += '<span class="word">' + list[current] +'</span>';
     current++;
     if (current >= list.length) {
         clearInterval(itv);
     }
 }, 1000);
```

Be sure to check [the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) which is very complete and pretty cool for web developers ;)